# In an array without an integer skip over it without throwing an error

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to create a method that takes an array as its argument and multiplies the number in the array to the arrays Index. When there is an element that is not a number i want to skip over it, and do not include it in the new array

E.g. add_index_to_array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) should return [0, 2, 6, 12, 20]

E.g. add_index_to_array(["A", 32, true, "B",  5.3, 0]) should return [32, 21.2, 0]

```
def add_index_to_array (array)
  new_array = array.map.with_index { |i,a| i * a}
  #if my array includes anything but a number return an empty array
end
puts add_index_to_array(['a',2,3,4])
# ["", 2, 6, 12]
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why is the result of your second example not `[32, 0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input

```
a = ["A", 32, true, "B", 5.3, 0,6]
```

Code

```
a.select { |x| x.is_a?(Numeric) }
    .map
    .with_index { |val, i| val * i }
#=>[0, 5.3, 0, 18]
```

I checked against Numeric class because your number could be Integer or Float.

Answer (score 1):

Following what you've tried until now, you can use `next` to pass to the next element in the array during the iteration unless the element is an Integer:

```
array.map.with_index do |i,a|
  next unless i.is_a?(Integer)
  i * a
end
```

That will leave nil values after an element is skiped, so you can use `compact` after all to remove them.

```
array.map.with_index do |i,a|
  next unless i.is_a?(Integer)
  i * a
end.compact
```

But really there are many ways. The easiest to understand (for me) - is to use `each_with_object` plus `with_index`, so you can get three objects during the iteration; the current element, an accumulator and the index. This way you can push to the accumulator the product of the current index and the current element only if the current element is an Integer:

```
array.each_with_object([]).with_index do |(e, array), index|
  array << index * e if e.is_a?(Integer)
end
```

---

Looking to your last example, it's clear you should be checking against Numeric objects instead of just Integer ones, since 5.3 isn't an Integer.